# Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm - doch was ist mit dem späten Wurm?

Tags: poetry, proverb

Ich habe ein nagendes, sprachliches Problem, und ich brauche Eure geschätzte Hilfe. Wie kann ich das Sprichwort "Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm" so ummünzen, abändern oder erweitern, dass der frühe Vogel der Depp ist, bzw. dass der Wurm der lange schläft als der Klügere oder der Weisere dasteht? Ich habe es gestrichen satt mir als gläubigen Langschläfer, Penner und Faulpelz diesen bescheuerten Spruch anhören zu müssen.

Nieder mit dem Vogel, hoch lebe der Wurm!

Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm, 
doch der späte Wurm [Wie weiter?]

... der lacht sich krumm? (Nein, doof, wir sind hier nicht im Kindergarten)
... foutiert sich drum? (Besser, aber... äh... nein...)
... doch es ist der späte Wurm, der triumphiert (meh, bloss weil der den Vogel verpasst, ist das noch kein Triumph...)

usw. HILFE!!!

Comment: Wenn, dann ist es der _späte Vogel_!

Comment: Dich selbst in die Position des _Wurms_ zu (ver-)setzen, ist vermutlich schon mal kontraproduktiv.

Comment: Nicht gerade klug oder weise, aber es werden Kaffeetassen verkauft mit dem Aufdruck _Der frühe Vogel kann mich mal_

Comment: Muss es eine Variation des Vogel/Wurm-Spruchs sein, oder wäre auch ein komplett anderes Sprichwort akzeptabel, solange es den Langschläfer u.a. feiert?

Comment: Die späte Maus kriegt den Speck, die frühe was ins Genick.

Comment: Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm, aber erst die zweite Maus bekommt den Käse.

Comment: Den mit der zweiten Maus kenne ich auch, die den Käse bekommt.

Comment: Der frühe Wurm *wird aufgefressen*! Depperter geht es doch gar nicht.

Comment: @Marzipanherz   Auch Postkarten mit diesem Spruch sind in Verkehr.

Comment: Vielleicht gibt dir eine Idee: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AA7Et_ZOPKI

Comment: @Christian: Und T-Shirts.

Comment: Das Sprichwort wurde aus dem Englischen übernommen, anscheinend war es bis in 1980-er Jahre in Deutschland unbekannt (http://www.einfachtierisch.de/tierisch/der-fruehe-vogel-faengt-den-wurm-eine-deutsche-redensart-id37280/). Also vielleicht auch mal auf https://english.stackexchange.com/ nachfragen.

Comment: Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm, der späte Vogel fängt die Maus.

Answer (score 9):

Wie wäre es mit

> Wer zu früh kommt, der muss länger warten.

in Anlehnung and das inzwischen ja schon reichlich abgenudelte *Wer zu spät kommt, den bestraft das Leben* (wieso eigentlich *das Leben*?).

**Hier noch eine Anmerkung zum Ausgangs-Sprichwort:**

Darf ich, die Debatte eine Stufe abstrahierend, anmerken, dass *Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm* kein schönes (hier im Sinne von: traditionelles) Sprichwort ist. Es ist eine erst vor Kürzerem ins Deutsche eingewanderte Übersetzung aus dem Englischen. Im Deutschen klingt es - mindestens für mein Ohr - fremd und hölzern.

Das traditionelle deutsche Äquivalent heißt ***Morgenstund hat Gold im Mund*** (warum eigentlich *im Mund*?). Du möchtest also vielleicht eine morgenruhefreundliche Version dessen. Vielleicht:

> Morgenstund hat Gold im Mund, doch langer Schlaf ist auch gesund.

(Dies allerdings sieht die Dinge eher aus der Position des Wurmes.)

Inhaltlich verwandt wäre noch die ebenfalls traditionelle Spruchweisheit ***Was du heute kannst besorgen, das verschiebe nicht auf morgen***. Zu der es dann auch entsprechende Gegenthesen gibt. Die fallen mir jetzt nur nicht ein. Ich füge sie noch an, wenn ich sie finde. Morgen vielleicht...

Comment: "das Leben" –– Please do not answer with questions. If you have a separate question… Couldn't resist. Aber Pedanten sind halt die größten Zeitbinder. Wenn nicht gar -verschwender. [No hurry](https://www.aphorismen.de/zitat/52950)

Comment: "Morgenstund hat Mief im Mund" und "Was du heute kannst besorgen, verschiebe schnell auf morgen, denn morgen hast du neue Sorgen".

Comment: Auch verwandt: "Wer schneller lebt, ist früher tot." (Aus dem goldenen Fundus ironischer Sprichwortparodien). Ebenso: "Wer langsam rennt, kommt auch ans Ziel."

Comment: Den Spruch "Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm" gab es in meiner Kindheit in den Niederlanden auch schon. Keine Ahnung woher der Spruch kam.

Comment: Übrigens: "Ambition is a poor excuse for not having sense enough to be lazy." -- Milan Kundera

Comment: (warum eigentlich Mund?) "im Mund" ist das Gold wohl nur, damit ein kleiner Reim entsteht: stund/Mund. Es heiß ja auch -stund und nicht -stunde.

Comment: Was du heute kannst besorgen, das verschiebe ruhig auf morgen

Comment: Noch ein Nachtrag zum "frühen Vogel": Der englische *early bird* ist vermutlich vor allem (und nur) deshalb populär, weil der Begriff mit seinen homophonen Teilen einen lautlichen Reiz hat: ***[ööli bööd]***. Auf Deutsch ***früher Vogel*** klingt dagegen einfach langweilig.

Answer (score 8):

Eine mir sehr bekannte Antwort auf den "frühen Wurm" lautet:

> Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm...
>
> ...aber erst die zweite Maus bekommt den Käse!

(in Bezug auf Mausefallen mit Käse als Köder)

Comment: genau mein Gedanke als ich diese Frage in der Übersicht hochploppen sah.

Comment: "Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm!" - "Aber die zweite Maus kriegt den Käse." Wegen der Würze der Kürze das "erst" streichen und "bekommt" durch "kriegt" ersetzen, und bitte mach die Erklärung der Pointe weg - das macht sie kaputt.

Comment: Das "erst" ist sprachlich geradezu notwendig und macht den Spruch erst schön. Das "erst" gehört dazu. "Kriegt" statt "bekommt" macht es etwas umgangssprachlicher, was OK sein kann. Die Erklärung habe ich dabei für Nicht-Muttersprachler. Den Tonfall deines Kommentar empfinde ich als unerfreulich besserwisserisch. Arbeite vielleicht mal an deinen eigenen Formulierungen statt an anderen herumzumäkeln.

Answer (score 7):

Ein etwas kindischer Spruch:

> Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm. Was kann man daran sehen? Für den Wurm wär's besser gewesen, später aufzustehen.

Answer (score 5):

Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm. Wer keine Würmer frühstücken will, kann noch im Bett bleiben.

Answer (score 4):

Der österreichische Kabarettist Michael Niavarani hat im Jahr 2011 ein Buch mit dem Titel

> [Der frühe Wurm hat einen Vogel](https://amalthea.at/produkt/der-fruehe-wurm-hat-einen-vogel/)

veröffentlicht.

Das lässt den frühen Wurm als großen Deppen dastehen, sagt aber leider nur indirekt etwas über den späten Wurm.

Zudem ist zumindest mir als Laie auch unklar, ob dieses Zitat allein (also nur dieser eine Satz, nicht das ganze Buch) schon ein Werk im Sinn des Urheberrechtes ist, was bestimmte rechtliche Konsequenzen bei der Verwertung des Zitats zur Folge hätte.

Answer (score 2):

Für mich ist die Antwort klar und simpel:

> Den frühen Wurm den fängt der Vogel!

Es handelt zwar nicht direkt vom späten Wurm, aber implizit. Es hat die bekannte Form und ist kurz und knackig! Möchte man die Reimstruktur exakt erhalten, wäre vorzuschlagen:

> Das frühe Würmchen fängt der Spatz/Specht...

Wenn unbedingt „später Wurm“ verbatim vorkommen muß, dann:

> Den späten Wurm, den fängt kein Vogel.

Dieser Spruch ist übrigens meines Erachtens viel sinniger als das Original. Wer Macht und Einfluß oder zumindest Erfolg hat, genießt es, wieder einmal zu sagen, wo‘s langgeht. Wer aber unter der Bürde des Lebens wankt, erfreut sich der Gnadenfrist im Schlafe.

Answer (score 1):

> - Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm – der späte nimmt ihn in Empfang.
> - Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm – der späte nimmt ihn entgegen.

Der späte lässt den frühen also für sich arbeiten.

Answer (score 1):

In den Kommentaren werden schon einige Sprichwörter ausgeschlachtet.
Hier sind noch ein paar Möglichkeiten.

Ein bestehendes (mir bislang unbekanntes) Sprichwort lautet wohl

> Vögel, die morgens singen, holt abends die Katze.

Die Bedeutung geht zwar eher in die Richtung von »Man soll die Haut des Bären nicht verkaufen, bevor er erlegt ist«, aber natürlich kann man es auch so interpretieren, dass nur die später singenden Vögel vor der Katze gefeit sind.

Wenn es eine [Kontamination](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/newsletter/Duden-Newsletter-260609) sein soll, wie etwa in Heinz Erhards »Wer den Schaden hat, spottet jeder Beschreibung«,

dann käme noch Folgendes in Betracht:

> Je später der Abend, desto schöner die Würmer.

Und wenn es ein bisschen ordinär sein darf

> Der frühe Vogel fängt den Wurm, aber der späte Wurm hat mehr Spaß beim Vögeln.

Comment: Auch
"Vögel, die früh singen, holt abends die Katze."
oder älter
"Die Vögel, die zu früh pfeifen, sind oft Abends von den Katzen gefressen."

Answer (score 1):

> Der frühe Vogel kann mich mal.

... hört man recht häufig.

Siehe bei [Mundmische](https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/25547-Der_fruehe_Vogel_kann_mich_mal) oder im [Leo Forum](https://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idforum=1&idThread=1046543&lp=ende&lang=de) oder als [Buch](https://www.buecher.de/shop/fachbuecher/der-fruehe-vogel-kann-mich-mal/hennig-bettina/products_products/detail/prod_id/32454655/).

Answer (score 0):

Den frühen Vogel frisst die späte Katze.

Answer (score 0):

Morgenstund' hat Gold im Mund. Und die anderen noch die ersten Zähne.