# What is the origin and meaning of the expression "Da wird der Hund in der Pfanne verrückt"?

Tags: etymology, idiom, expression

I heard this expression several times at work and wonder what it exactly means and where it originates from. I moved to the south of Germany close to Stuttgart.

Comment: This can be found in [Redensarten-Index](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=Da+wird+der+Hund+in+der+Pfanne+verr%C3%BCckt&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&sp0=rart_ou&sp1=rart_varianten_ou). The story given there is that it's a Till Eulenspiegel reference.

Comment: @RDBury: Und warum fasst Du nicht den Inhalt d. Redensartenindex zusammen und präsentierst es als Antwort? Andere haben sicher Hemmungen diese bereits per Kommentar gegebene Antwort auch formal als Antwort zu geben, da dies nach Reputationsgier aussieht.

Answer (score 2):

This is an (idiomatic) nonsense-phrase expressing astonishment or puzzlement up to dumbfundedness. A similar phrase in English would be "Oh, my god!", "(This is driving me) Crazy!", "No Shit!" or the like.

The word-by-word meaning is "With this the dog in the pan will get crazy." This translation makes as much sense as the german original and is an example for nonsense-humor in dialect. You will find this phrase throughout the southern german regiolects. It is also known in Austria.

There are similar phrases like i.e. (this is common in Vienna - i haven't heard it anywhere else)

> Bruada ums Eck!

Word-by-word this is "brother(,) around the corner" and it also expresses puzzlement about something drastically not being or happening as expected.

All these phrases are colloquially used and - even if said in Standard High German - definitely not formal speech.

Answer (score 1):

Das fehlen eines glaubwürdigen Ursprungs - vgl. Ansätze bei Röhrich, Lexikon der sprichwörtlichen Redensarten - bedarf eines Umwegs, vgl. englisch *pen*:

> **pen** (n.2)

> "small enclosure for domestic animals," Old English *penn, penne*, **a word of uncertain origin**, perhaps related to Old English *pinn* "pin, peg" [...]

Das Bild eines *Geheges* ("enclosure") kann als Grundbegriff gelten, der auf semantischer Ebene ähnlich primitiv ist wie die graphische Darstellung.

So bildet das chinesische Radikal 囗 etwa einen Teil von 圍 "to surround; all sides; [...]" ab (und zwar rekursiv, das Zeichen in der Mitte) und ebenso 欄圈 "pen; animal yard" (die Umrandung). Ähnlich verhalten sich ägyptische Hieroglypen, so z.B. der lateinische Buchstabe H über einen von verschiedenen Umwegen aus ägyptisch *h*  unilateral ⟨h⟩ als in /hɛ/ "courtyard *?*" hergeleitet wird (Wiktionary), jedoch leicht mit  /pɛr/ "house" etc. p.p. verwechselt werden kann. Im Endeffekt ist das also nicht eindeutig, was im wesentlichen die Architektur betrifft. Auf Sprachlicher Ebene ist seit Lackoff und Johnson, Metaphors We Live By (1980), die Bedeutsamkeit räumlicher Metaphern weitgehend anerkennt.

Dieses ist relevant, weil *in der Pfanne* -- die adverbiale Präposition -- kaum einen anderen Schluss zulässt. Da im übrigen auszuschließen ist, eine Bratpfanne industriellen Maßstabs könne einen Hund in absurder Weise beinhalten, ist der Spruch quasi ein *Rätsel*, der unlogische Schluss des unwissenden -- die Pointe -- der Hund werde gebraten. *Da brat mir doch einer'n Storch* wäre sogar geeignet, jenen Schluss zu bestätigen. Im Umkehrschluss ist ein Durchdrehen aufgebrachter Wachhunde durchaus bemerkenswert. Das ist schließlich ihr Job. Ferner kann man sprichwörtlich z.B. auch *die jungen Pferde scheu machen*. Hier würde es jedoch zu weit führen, auf die entsprechenden Haltungsformen einzugehen, da der gemeine Stadtmensch offenbar kein Verständnis für die Hundehaltung hat und alle gleich als Kuscheltiere behandelt.

Die Ähnlichkeit liegt also maximal darin, dass *pen* im allgemeinen und *Pfanne* im speziellen Kontext keine sichere Deutung haben. Eventuel hilft mitteldeutsch *pan, ban, espan* weiter (q.v. mhdbw-online.de) Ebenso unsicher wäre Anschluss an *Penne* in Gaunersprache "Nachtunterkunft" (cp. [Penner](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/56180/35977)), Studentensprache "Schule"

Für Hunde gibt es streng genommen aber nur den Platz im Gehege, eher als in freier Wild-*Bahn*. Daher liegt der Anschluss an die allgemeinere Bedeutung nah. Lautlich ist das ohnehin schwierig, da *p ungermanisch ist und *(*p)f kontraindiziert ist, also vielleicht auch älter. Auch eher unwahrscheinlich ist eine ursprüngliche Bezeichnung der Pferde (s.o.) mit dem längst untergegangen Wortverwandten zu lat. *equus*, was weitreichende Remotivation erfordern würde, um insbesondere auf Bauernschaft zu schließen (vgl. althochdeutsch *ehu-*).

Comment: Was spricht denn gegen die per Kommentar gegebene Antwort, es ginge auf Till Eulenspiegel zurück?

Comment: Hast Du schon mal eine Pfanne in der Gastronomie gesehen oder beim Militär? Oder gar in der Industrie? Es ist keineswegs auszuschließen, eine Bratpfanne  im eigentlichen Sinne könne einen Hund im eigentlichen Sinne beinhalten. Das Gegenteil ist wahr, wenn man den Horizont eines Singlehaushalts transzendiert.

Comment: gut aber da brät man so ein großes Tier nicht am Stück und sicher nicht lebendig.

Comment: Es heißt "Da wird der Hund in der Pfanne verrückt" - von einer heißen Pfanne, in der er gebraten wird, müsste nicht die Rede sein. Außer man folgt der Theorie, wonach es auf Eulenspiegel zurückgeht, und eigentlich der Hopfen, nicht der Hund Hopf, gebraten werden soll - wohl in der Brauerei, sprich vorindustrielle Größenordnung von Hopfen und somit der Pfanne, wahrscheinlich ganz locker groß genug, um Schäferhunde, Dobermänner, Bernhardiner und ganze Rinder zu braten. Wir wären dann auch im Bereich der phantastischen Literatur, in der am laufenden Meter Lebendiges vernichtet wird, s.a. Max&Mor.

Comment: "Die Redensart selbst ist allerdings erst in der ersten Hälfte des 20. Jahrhunderts entstanden", lt. Redensarten-Index @RDBury

Comment: Was soll mir das sagen? Willst Du behaupten, dass Redensarten, die auf Werke zurückgehen, immer eng zum Zeitpunkt der Werke entstehen müssen? Vielleicht wurde Eulenspiegel zur vorletzten Jahrhundertwende besonders populär, vielleicht durch eine Verfilmung?

Comment: Wieso "das"? Ich gehe beim Zitierten noch von "er,", "sie" o.ä. aus. Was die dir damit sagen wollen, wäre wohl deren Sache, beinhaltet für meinen Teil offenbar berechtigte Zweifel ob der Möglichkeit eines Zfalls.

Comment: Übrifmgens "will" ich hier garnichts. Hoch- und runter-willen kann ich nur die Antworten anderer. Ich mein ja nur, Literaturstudenten könnten besonders geneigt sein den Ursprung in der Literatur zu suchen, genauso wie das Aufkommen. Falls beides nicht zutrifft, muss jene Methode versagen. Der Ansatz ist wohl richtig, einen möglichst engen Bezug zum Ursprung zu suchen. Der mir unbekannte Eulenspiegel-Stoff ist insofern egal, weil der etwaige Hund damit noch lange nicht *verrückt* wird. Andernfalls möchte man eine gewisse Nähe zu *Penne* sehen, falls dies zutrifft.

Comment: Andernfalls, oder falls dies zutrifft? Auch möchte man nicht  eine gewisse Nähe zu Penne sehen - Du willst das.

Comment: Naja, ja, exemplar gratia.

Comment: 如果这不是废话 (rúguǒ zhè bùshì fèihuà)

Comment: @KritikerderElche, Gesundheit! Beim Versuch eine Übersetzung in Mandarin für “mach nicht die jungen Pferde scheu” zu finden, fehlt mir zwar die Expertise, doch steht da tatsächlich bei en.wiktionary **“to cook someone's goose”** (“The first recorded use of this colloquial phrase was in 1851.”, dictionary.com) als Synonym zu “upset the applecart” (via dict.cc: “Pferde”), das wiederum zu deutsch “die Suppe versalzen” verlinkt ist (WT). Man sagt ja, in China essen sie Hunde, aber das ist doch wirklich feinstes 話 *huà*. Den Hinweis auf 話 kann ich nicht annehmen, 不可偏廢.