# "Penner" as an original etymology

Tags: etymology

See prior question about its meaning: [Penner as an Insult?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/27665/penner-as-an-insult).

Pfeifer gives indecisive derivations from Yiddish, Hebrew and Gaunersprache, as if there are no older German cognates: 1. "jiddisch *pannai* ‘müßig’, hebr. *penaj* ‘(freie) Zeit’, or 2. "*Bonne* ‘ein Haus, wo Spitzbuben ein und aus gehen’ (Ende 17. Jh.)", "Vielleicht zu jidd. *bono* ‘er hat gebaut’" (dwds.de).

Bavarian does in fact have a root *pno-* in seemingly onomatopoeic meaning (Bayerisches Wörterbuch, Bayerische Akademie der Wissenschaften), which corresponds to English *sneeze*, older *fnesen*, also Greek *pnein* "breath" (etymonline.com, lsj.gr, which see for more). This appears to be archaic and it evidently includes a sense of snoring = sleeping in Bavarian.

Why are etymologists *snoozing* on this root?

<sub>Note also the *Bett* in *bettelnder Bettler*. The semantic range of *lying down, on the ground* etc. is fairly wide!</sub>